# SQL Server / Create view from stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I am trying to create a view out of a stored procedure and am perplexed to see two opposing results from a very similar approach.

**Example 1**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE cv AS
GO
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(MAX)
SET @sql = 'CREATE VIEW test AS SELECT * FROM someOtherTable'
exec (@sql)
```

Whereas this example creates the view once the procedure is created for the 1st time, it will not recreate the view when I execute the procedure at a later stage using:

```
EXEC cv
```

**Example 2**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE cv 
@table SYSNAME
AS
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(MAX)
SET @sql = 'CREATE VIEW '+ @table +' AS SELECT * FROM someOtherTable'
```

This one instead does not create the view when the procedure is created for the first time but creates the view afterwards every time it is called by:

```
EXEC @sql;
```

Why is this the case? I think this is really confusing and does not make sense or does it?

Comment: `CREATE PROCEDURE` mean create procedure not view. When you execute SP then you call `CREATE VIEW` which is creates view.

Comment: It's wrong. Calling the same create view multiple times does not work. You must drop the view before creating it again.

Comment: CREATE PROCEDURE only creates the procedure not any Objects referring inside that procedure. Your observation about the 1st procedure is wrong, it cannot possibly create the view for you by just creating that procedure.

Comment: Also you are just creating the SP. Running that SP ill create a view. When you say creating the SP creates the view it's not correct

Answer (score 3):

For your 1st statement

```
CREATE PROCEDURE cv AS
GO                      --<-- This GO here terminates the batch
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(MAX)
SET @sql = 'CREATE VIEW test AS SELECT * FROM someOtherTable'
exec (@sql)
```

the `GO` batch terminator create the procedure and the EXECUTES the following statement straightaway. So it appears to you as you have created a procedure which created the view for you.

Infact these are two statements in two batches.

--BATCH 1

```
CREATE PROCEDURE cv AS
GO
```

--BATCH 2

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(MAX)
SET @sql = 'CREATE VIEW test AS SELECT * FROM someOtherTable'
exec (@sql)
```

Batch 1 Creates a procedure which has nothing inside it, but it creates a procedure object for you with no functionality/Definition at all.

Statement after the key word `GO` is executed separately and creates the view for you.

**My Suggestion**

Always check for an object's existence before you create it. I would write the procedure something like this..

```
CREATE PROCEDURE cv 
AS
BEGIN
 SET NOCOUNT ON;

IF OBJECT_ID ('test', 'V') IS NOT NULL
 BEGIN
   DROP VIEW test
 END

    DECLARE @sql nvarchar(MAX)
    SET @sql = 'CREATE VIEW test AS SELECT * FROM someOtherTable'
    exec (@sql)
END
```

Answer (score 0):

In Example 1 - you are creating a view with a hard-coded name of test. On subsequent runs of your proc, as the view already exists, SQL Server will throw an error because you are trying to create a view with the same name as one that already exists.

In Example 2, you are passing in the name of the view as a parameter. This will always create a new view unless the @table value you pass in corresponds to an existing view.

Just wondering - why are you creating a view with a stored proc? This is not something you would normally do in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change

`EXEC @sql` to EXEC `(sql)`

EXEC can be use to run stored procedure, not dynamic sql

eg.

```
declare @dd varchar(100)='Select ''A'''

exec (@dd) ->will work fine
exec @dd   -> Error
```

Read more about [The Curse and Blessings of Dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html)

Comment: see my answer to this question, it does work :) the issue is with `GO` in the middle of procedure definition.

Comment: @M.Ali : Sorry I didn't get you!! What is working? I just indicate the OP, how to execute `dynamic sql`

Answer (score 0):

Create view statement cannot be used with a stored procedure

Comment: OK, i see on two occassions that a view should not be used inside a stored procedure. My rationale to create a procedure to create a  view was to have an easy way to update (by recreating) the view by just calling it conveniently through the EXEC statement. Is there a better way to achieve a VIEW update?

Answer (score 0):

```
EXEC ('CREATE VIEW ViewName AS SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(Yourservername,''EXECUTE [databasename].[dbo].[sp_name] ''''' +Parameter + ''''''')')
```

Comment: This answer was flagged as low-quality automatically. Some additional explanation as well as the code would be a big help to readers trying to understand what this does. Thanks!